# logic behind the proof for forgetfulness of geometric distributions

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, geometric-series

I am currently trying to prove the forgetfulness property of geometric distributions (in neutral language: modelling the number of tails before the first heads in a sequence of coin flips) by showing the following: P(X = n + k | X >= n) = P(X = k). I have already proved the property (for a geometric distribution where *P(X) = p^n(1-p)*) but I am having troubling wrapping my head around the logic of one of the steps (bolded below).

P(X = n + k | X >= n) = P(X = n + k, X >= n) / P(X >= n)

= P(X = n + k)/P(X >= n)

= p^(n+k) * (1-p) / **P(X >= n)**

= p^(n+k) * (1-p) / **[sum(p^k * (p-1)), k=n to infinity]**

= p^(n+k) * (1-p) / **p^n**

= p^k * (1-p)

= P(X = k)

I understand that *P(X >= n)* is just the sum of an infinite geometric series so you can calculate it and obtain p^n (this is straightforward). **However, could someone explain to me, in words, why the sum of the probabilities for *X >= n* is *p^n*, the probability of obtaining n tails in a row?** I just don't understand why this is the case. Someone told me that it is *p^n* because all events in *X >= n* contain sequences that start off *n* tails but this explanation doesn't make much sense to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any sequence of heads and tails, one *cannot* simultaneously have any two of

- $n$ tails then first head
- $n+1$ tails then the first head
- $n+2$ tails then the first head
- ...

because each pair of these differ.  That is, these are disjoint events -- if you find yourself in a universe described by one of these, you are not simultaneously in a universe described by another of these.  This means we *add* the probabilities of these outcomes to find the total probability that any of these outcomes occurs.  (If these were not disjoint, we would need to perform an inclusion-exclusion analysis on their overlaps so that we would not overcount the total probability.)  These are $P(X = n)$, $P(X = n+1)$, ... and we have argued
$$ P(X \geq n) = \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} P(X=i)  \text{.}$$

The one thing these all have in common is they start with $n$ tails in a row.  In fact, *every* possible way to start with $n$ tails in a row is in that list.  No sequence of coin flip outcomes starting with fewer than $n$ tails in a row is on that list.  So collectively, these count the probability of all the ways to start with $n$ tails and then do *anything* afterwards, which is to say, these count the probability of all the ways to start with $n$ tails.  Since each tail independently has probability $p$, we have
$$ P(X \geq n) = p^n  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Please let me know if I am understanding this correctly. If we consider event A to be *n* tails in a row, then an event B (*n* + 1 tails then the first head) would be within the sample space of event A. All events that start with *n* tails lie within the sample space of A, thus the sum of probabilities these events, or *P(X >= n)*, would simply equal *P(A) = p^n*. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: I agree with your description of your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathsf P(X=n) ~=~p^n(1-p)\mathbf 1_{n\in\Bbb N}$ where $p$ is the rate of "tails" results among a sequence of iid coin tosses, means that $X$ is the count of tails *before* the first head.

> However, could someone explain to me, in words, why the sum of the probabilities for $X \geqslant n$ is $p^n$, the probability of obtaining n tails in a row?

If you will obtain $n$ tails in the first $n$ tosses, then it shall take at least those $n$ tosses before the first head.

If it will take at least $n$ tosses before the first head, then the first $n$ tosses shall all be tails.

The descriptions are equivalent; they are the same event.

So the probability for taking at least $n$ tosses before the first head is $p^n$, since this is the probability for obtaining $n$ consequetive tails among the first $n$ tosses.

---

In symbols, it is due to the Geometric Series: $$\sum_{k=n}^\infty p^k(1-p)~{=~p^n(1-p)\sum_{j=0}^\infty p^j\\=p^n(1-p)\tfrac1{1-p}\\=p^n}$$